# How do you play slap + specific strings at the same time?

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, technique, acoustic-guitar

Here's an example the tab

`e|-----0-----0--
B|--0--0--0--0--
G|--0--0-----0--
D|--------------
E|--x--3--x--3--`

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you sure the `x` denote “slap”, and what do you mean by that anyway?

Comment: Yeah maybe an example video would help us understand what you're talking about. That tab offers almost no information. It doesn't even show six strings. Or maybe it's not showing up correctly for me.

Comment: doesnt the X denote a muted note, rather than a slap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no real "trick" to being able to play both the percussive slap and strike the notes at the same time. You start SLOW, and practice just hitting the slap and flicking the string(s) at the same time by either using sort of a downward stroke with just the pointer finger, or by sorta cupping the other fingers (apart from the thumb, which is performing the "slap") and using those multiple fingers to hit multiple strings. Slow focused repetition, as always, will yield predictable results for those simply willing to set down and do it. Set a timer, and just do this over and over. Practice slapping and hitting one string, make an exercise and set the timer/metronome and get to work. 
Ex: slap the low E string and pluck the high E with your finger (so that no other strings sound). Do the same but only plucking the b string, etc. Over and over. For how long? Well, how good to you want to be at it? :)

This is a tricky part of learning and really being able to implement that percussive "slap" you're referring to. It does not come naturally at first, but neither did anything you've learned on guitar--learning this is a reminder of how slow and methodical you had to be learning simple things early on, like fretting notes, hammer-ons, whatever, being able to play cleanly and transition between chord shapes...all those things required a LOT of effort early on, maybe seemed impossible at times, and now those times are hard to even remember and appreciate. So don't get frustrated cuz this technique is a bit advanced! But worth it without a doubt.